# VSCode isn't changing default settings when reinstalled

Tags: visual-studio-code

I previously configured my VSCode to use Fish as its default shell. After deciding I wanted to change it, I reinstalled VSCode. Even after installing, however, the default settings were not changed. They look like this

```
  // The path of the shell that the terminal uses on Linux.
  "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/local/bin/fish",

  // The path of the shell that the terminal uses on OS X.
  "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/usr/local/bin/fish"
```

I've tried overriding these settings in user settings to no avail, the terminal won't launch because I don't have fish installed.

Comment: Do you see the `fish` settings when you open the raw default settings? Open the command palette and type `Raw Default Settings` to view those.

Comment: Perhaps the `defaults` command can help?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yes, it still shows up as 

```
 // The path of the shell that the terminal uses on Linux.
  "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/local/bin/fish",

  // The path of the shell that the terminal uses on OS X.
  "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/usr/local/bin/fish",
```

Comment: @PaulStelian is that a CLI command or command palette command?

Comment: Those are not the default values for those settings in vscode. You are probably looking at your user settings. If not, maybe post a screenshot of what you're looking at.

Comment: @Charles `defaults` is a macOS CLI command. You need to figure out the parameters yourself as I don't have an actual macOS system on my hand right now.

Comment: @RobLourens Those are the default vscode settings for my vscode unfortunately. Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/Gveqk